# Text ID = Password... will not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The password input isn't working... check it:

```
    <div class="form">
  <h2>Login Form</h2><br />
        <form method="POST" id="login-form">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
```

I apologize for being unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry... what is the problem.. what is not working

Comment: should be `<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">`

Comment: maybe you want `type="password"` on the password field?

Comment: Resolved, thanks guys :P -- Small little error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing type here. To get password field,Input type should be password

Try like this

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type="password"` instead of `type="text"`. See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2cLueb3d/)